# Boundary of the complex p-adic unit disk?

Tags: general-topology, p-adic-number-theory

Take the complex $p$-adic filled unit disk: for some prime $p$, this is the set D = {c $\in$ $\mathbb{C}_p$ : |c|$_p$ $\leq$ $1$}, where $\mathbb{C}_p$ is the algebraically closed and complete field under the p-adic absolute value.

From a non-$p$-adic intuition, I would think the boundary of this set is S = {c $\in$ $\mathbb{C}_p$ : |c|$_p$ = $1$}. Is this correct? Does closure in p-adic land work the same way regardless of topological space? How could I rigorously determine the boundary?

Comment: For $c$ to be on the boundary of a set $D$ it has to be the case that any open ball containing $c$ contains points of $D$ and points of the complement of $D$. Does $S$ meet this requirement?

Comment: I struggle with how balls work in this space. Cp is totally disconnected, and the p-adic norm is unintuitive. If I start by choosing a c such that the p-adic norm is 1, I can consider the small disk around containing points x where |c-x| is less than some arbitrary small epsilon. But then things get weird depending on what the p-adic norm of x is, and I'm not sure how to show there are or aren't some x in that disk such that the norm is LARGER than 1.

Comment: To add - balls in this space can never be only partially intersecting. They are either disjoint, or one is contained in the other. Every point contained in a ball is the center of that ball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: It's straightforward to see that $D$ is closed; use the ultrametric property to show that it is also open.

If a set is both closed and open, what is its boundary according to the topological definition?

Comment: Oh dear - if the set is clopen, then the boundary is empty. What if my next task is to show that a set of points is dense in the boundary?

Comment: That's tough unless that set of points is empty itself, because otherwise it's not contained in the boundary. Maybe your source uses "boundary" not in the standard topological sense but actually means the set $S$ you proposed? I feel like I have seen that abuse of terminology.